# How to fix vertical artifact lines in a vertex array in SFML, WITH pixel perfect zoom/move?

Tags: c++, sfml

I have been working on a 2D top-down game solely in SFML and C++, that has a tilemap. I cannot rid the tilemap of vertical line artifacts when zooming in and out or moving the render view at different zoom levels. I attached an image below of the problem; circled in red.

[image: Problem with gap between squares]

#### [edit]

**There are a lot of factors that make this bug inconsistent.
If I use a tile_atlas from only one tile, there is no artifacts. If I map each texture to a tile a.k.a not using vertex arrays; I did not see any artifacts but it is anywhere from 10x to 15x slower with the same number of tiles on the screen. I have tried finding zoom levels that don't cause artifacts, and there are some. but the levels are almost random and makes zoom in and out, not smooth and choppy.**

I have tried numerous tutorials and forum "fixes" that have not completely worked. I have completely rewrote the underlying tile engine 4 separate times to no avail.

https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=15747.0

topic=14504

topic=5952

topic=13637.15

https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-view.php

https://www.binpress.com/creating-city-building-game-with-sfml/

https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-vertex-array.php

#### [edit]

**I have read the Terreria scaling issue, the fix to make extra large textures then scale, or multiple textures, one for each zoom level. seem exhaustive. I am looking for a programmatic way of achieving the scaling correctly.**

This is post is my last attempt to fix the code, otherwise I will need to change languages.

I believe the main issue comes from the zoom in/out functions of the program.
I have tried many, variations/attempt to get this to work +0.5f offset,+0.375f offset, not pixel perfect

```
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::E))
        {
            float zoom_in = 0.995f;

            float nz = last_sq * zoom_in;
            nz = std::floor(nz);
            float now = nz / last_sq;
            if (nz <= 10)
                continue;
            last_sq = nz;

            std::cout << now << std::endl;

            cam.zoom(now);
        }


        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
        {
            cam.move(0.f, -0.02f);
            float x = cam.getCenter().x;
            float y = cam.getCenter().y;
            x = std::floor(x);
            y = std::floor(y);
            //std::cout << "x: " << x << "\ty: " << y << std::endl;
            cam.setCenter(x, y);
        }
```

Here is the entire code.

#### main.cpp

```cpp
#include "chunk_map.h"
#include "tile_atlas.h"
#include <vector>
//#include "main.h"
#include "map.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <SFML/Graphics/RenderWindow.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/View.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window/Event.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window/Keyboard.hpp>

#include "animation_handler.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    sf::RenderWindow app(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "Tilemap Example");
    // Hard set fps to monitor refresh rate.

    // textures to load.
    /*text_mgr.loadTexture("grass", "grass.png");
    text_mgr.loadTexture("high_grass", "high_grass.png");

    Animation staticAnim(0, 0, 1.0f);
    tileAtlas["grass"] = Tile(32, 1, text_mgr.getRef("grass"),{ staticAnim },
            TileType::GRASS, 50, 0, 1);

    tileAtlas["high_grass"] = Tile(32, 1, text_mgr.getRef("high_grass"),{ staticAnim },
        TileType::HIGH_GRASS, 100, 0, 1);*/

    //Map map;

    //map.load(50, 50, tileAtlas);

    #ifdef NDEBUG
    app.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);
    std::cout << "#################\n";
    #endif // DEBUG
    //app.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);
    sf::View cam = app.getDefaultView();

    tile_atlas atlas = tile_atlas();

    std::vector<chunk_map> map;

    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        {
            map.push_back(chunk_map());
            map.back().set_texture(atlas.get_atlas());
            map.back().set_position(10 * x, 10 * y, 10 * (x + 1), 10 * (y + 1));
            map.back().load_tiles();
        }
    }

    sf::Clock clock;
    int checked = 0;
    int last_sq = 600;

    while (app.isOpen())
    {
        //sf::Time elapsed = clock.restart();
        //float dt = elapsed.asSeconds();

        sf::Event eve;
        while (app.pollEvent(eve))
            if (eve.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                app.close();


        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::P))
            std::cout << "view x: " << cam.getSize().x << "\tview y: " << cam.getSize().y << std::endl;


        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Q))
        {
            float zoom_out = 1.005f;

            float nz = last_sq * zoom_out;
            nz = std::ceil(nz);
            float now = nz / last_sq;
            last_sq = nz;

            std::cout << now << std::endl;

            cam.zoom(now);
            //float x = cam.getCenter().x;
            //float y = cam.getCenter().y;
            //x = std::floor(x);
            //y = std::floor(y);
            ////std::cout << "x: " << x << "\ty: " << y << std::endl;
            //cam.setCenter(x, y);
        }


        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::E))
        {
            float zoom_in = 0.995f;

            float nz = last_sq * zoom_in;
            nz = std::floor(nz);
            float now = nz / last_sq;
            if (nz <= 10)
                continue;
            last_sq = nz;

            std::cout << now << std::endl;

            cam.zoom(now);
            //float x = cam.getCenter().x;
            //float y = cam.getCenter().y;
            //x = std::floor(x);
            //y = std::floor(y);
            ////std::cout << "x: " << x << "\ty: " << y << std::endl;
            //cam.setCenter(x, y);
        }


        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
        {
            cam.move(0.f, -0.02f);
            float x = cam.getCenter().x;
            float y = cam.getCenter().y;
            x = std::floor(x);
            y = std::floor(y);
            //std::cout << "x: " << x << "\ty: " << y << std::endl;
            cam.setCenter(x, y);
        }


        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
        {
            cam.move(-0.02f, 0.f);
            float x = cam.getCenter().x;
            float y = cam.getCenter().y;
            x = std::floor(x);
            y = std::floor(y);
            //std::cout << "x: " << x << "\ty: " << y << std::endl;
            cam.setCenter(x, y);
        }


        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
        {
            cam.move(0.f, 0.02f);
            float x = cam.getCenter().x;
            float y = cam.getCenter().y;
            x = std::ceil(x);
            y = std::ceil(y);
            //std::cout << "x: " << x << "\ty: " << y << std::endl;
            cam.setCenter(x, y);
        }


        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
        {
            cam.move(0.02f, 0.f);
            float x = cam.getCenter().x;
            float y = cam.getCenter().y;
            x = std::ceil(x);
            y = std::ceil(y);
            //std::cout << "x: " << x << "\ty: " << y << std::endl;
            cam.setCenter(x, y);
        }


        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
        {
            sf::Time elapsed = clock.getElapsedTime();
            float t = elapsed.asSeconds();
            int time = std::floor(t);

            if (checked < time)
            {
                checked = time;

                cam.move(0.01f, 0.f);
                float x = cam.getCenter().x;
                float y = cam.getCenter().y;
                x = std::ceil(x);
                y = std::ceil(y);
                std::cout << "x: " << x << "\ty: " << y << std::endl;
                cam.setCenter(x, y);
            }
        }


        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape))
            app.close();

        app.setView(cam);

    #ifdef _DEBUG
        app.clear();
    #endif // DEBUG
        //map.draw(app, dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            app.draw(map.at(i));
        }

        app.display();
    }
}
```

#### chunk_map.h

```
#pragma once


#include <SFML/Graphics/Drawable.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Texture.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/VertexArray.hpp>
#include <vector>


class chunk_map : public sf::Drawable
{
private:
    //change values of these to match your needs and improve performance
    enum { tilesize = 32, chunksize = 32};

    //tile size float
    float tile_size_float = 32.0f;

    // Draw chunk
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states)const;

    // texture for chunk
    sf::Texture m_texture;

    // chunk dimensions
    int tiles_per_chunk_x;
    int tiles_per_chunk_y;

    //start x and y and ending x and y scaled to tile size. a.k.a. 
    // 1,1 = tile 1,1. 10,10, equals tile 10,10
    int chunk_start_x;
    int chunk_start_y;

    int chunk_end_x;
    int chunk_end_y;

    // Vertex array of positions of tiles in chunk
    std::vector<std::vector<sf::VertexArray> > m_chunks;

    // Append tiles.
    void append_tile(int gx, int gy, sf::VertexArray& garr);

public:
    chunk_map();
    ~chunk_map();
    void load_tiles();


    void set_texture(sf::Texture);
    void set_position(int chunk_start_x, int chunk_start_y,
        int chunk_end_x, int chunk_end_y);

};
```

#### chunk_map.cpp

```
#include "chunk_map.h"

#include <SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.hpp>
#include <SFML/System/Vector2.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Vertex.hpp>

chunk_map::chunk_map()
{
}

chunk_map::~chunk_map()
{
}


void chunk_map::load_tiles()
{
    /*

        Tile loading this is were the tiles are added to the Quadrantics of the tilemap.
        this is the entire chunk_map loop

    */
    if ((chunk_end_x * chunk_end_y) == 0)//empty map - possibly forgotten to fill data struct
    {
        //to stop displaying at all after failed loading:
        tiles_per_chunk_x = 0;
        tiles_per_chunk_y = 0;
        m_chunks.clear();
        return;
    }

    chunk_map::tiles_per_chunk_x = (chunk_end_x / chunksize) + 1;
    chunk_map::tiles_per_chunk_y = (chunk_end_y / chunksize) + 1;
    m_chunks.assign(tiles_per_chunk_x, std::vector<sf::VertexArray>(tiles_per_chunk_y, sf::VertexArray(sf::Quads)));//ready up empty 2d arrays
    for (int iy = chunk_start_y; iy < chunk_end_y; ++iy)
    {
        for (int ix = chunk_start_x; ix < chunk_end_x; ++ix)
        {
            append_tile(ix, iy, m_chunks[ix / chunksize][iy / chunksize]);
        }
    }
}


void chunk_map::append_tile(int gx, int gy, sf::VertexArray& garr)
{
    /*

        This  is the specific tile vertex, broken from the other function to decrease complexitity.

    */

    int tile_selection_index_x = rand() % 2;
    int tile_selection_index_y = 0;

    float f_tx = tile_selection_index_x * tile_size_float;
    float f_ty = tile_selection_index_y * tile_size_float;


    sf::Vertex ver;

    //____________________________________________________________________________________________________________
    ver.position = sf::Vector2f(gx * tile_size_float, gy * tile_size_float);
    //texture in position of text atlas
    //top left corner
    //ver.texCoords = sf::Vector2f( 0.f, 0.f);
    ver.texCoords = sf::Vector2f(f_tx, f_ty);
    garr.append(ver);

    //____________________________________________________________________________________________________________
    ver.position = sf::Vector2f(gx * tile_size_float + tile_size_float, gy * tile_size_float);
    //texture in position of text atlas
    //top right corner
    //ver.texCoords = sf::Vector2f( tile_size_float, 0.f);
    ver.texCoords = sf::Vector2f(f_tx + tile_size_float, f_ty);
    garr.append(ver);

    //____________________________________________________________________________________________________________
    ver.position = sf::Vector2f(gx * tile_size_float + tile_size_float, gy * tile_size_float + tile_size_float);
    //texture in position of text atlas
    //bottom right corner
    //ver.texCoords = sf::Vector2f( tile_size_float,  tile_size_float);
    ver.texCoords = sf::Vector2f(f_tx + tile_size_float, f_ty + tile_size_float);
    garr.append(ver);

    //____________________________________________________________________________________________________________
    ver.position = sf::Vector2f(gx * tile_size_float, gy * tile_size_float + tile_size_float);
    //texture in position of text atlas
    //bottom left corner
    //ver.texCoords = sf::Vector2f( 0.f,  tile_size_float);
    ver.texCoords = sf::Vector2f(f_tx, f_ty + tile_size_float);
    garr.append(ver);
}


void chunk_map::set_texture(sf::Texture t)
{
    /*

        Sets the texture data for this chunk map from the texture atlas.

    */

    m_texture = t;

    // TODO test this feature
    // Attempt to optimize tearing on zooming to a different view.
    //m_texture.setSmooth(true);
}


void chunk_map::set_position(int chunk_start_x, int chunk_start_y,
    int chunk_end_x, int chunk_end_y)
{
    /*

        Initialize the accordinates of the start of the chunk_map to the end.

    */
    chunk_map::chunk_start_x = chunk_start_x;
    chunk_map::chunk_start_y = chunk_start_y;

    chunk_map::chunk_end_x = chunk_end_x;
    chunk_map::chunk_end_y = chunk_end_y;
}


void chunk_map::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states)const
{
    /*

        The actual draw call to this specific chunk_map

    */


    // position variables for this draw.
    int left = 0;
    int right = 0;
    int top = 0;
    int bottom = 0;


    //get top left point of view
    sf::Vector2f temp = target.getView().getCenter() - (target.getView().getSize() / 2.f);


    //get top left point of view
    left = static_cast<int>(temp.x / (chunksize * tilesize));
    top = static_cast<int>(temp.y / (chunksize * tilesize));


    //get bottom right point of view
    temp += target.getView().getSize();
    right = 1 + static_cast<int>(temp.x / (chunksize * tilesize));
    bottom = 1 + static_cast<int>(temp.y / (chunksize * tilesize));


    //clamp these to fit into array bounds:
    left = std::max(0, std::min(left, tiles_per_chunk_x));
    top = std::max(0, std::min(top, tiles_per_chunk_y));
    right = std::max(0, std::min(right, tiles_per_chunk_x));
    bottom = std::max(0, std::min(bottom, tiles_per_chunk_y));


    //set texture and draw visible chunks:
    states.texture = &m_texture;



    for (int ix = left; ix < right; ++ix)
    {
        for (int iy = top; iy < bottom; ++iy)
        {
            target.draw(m_chunks[ix][iy], states);
        }
    }
}
```

#### tile_atlas.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics/Texture.hpp>
class tile_atlas
{
private:
    sf::Texture atlas_texture;
public:
    tile_atlas();
    ~tile_atlas();
    sf::Texture& get_atlas();
};
```

#### tile_atlas.cpp

```
#include "tile_atlas.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


tile_atlas::tile_atlas()
{
    std::string file_string = "tilemap_test.png";
    if (!atlas_texture.loadFromFile(file_string))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed loading file: " << file_string << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

tile_atlas::~tile_atlas()
{
}

sf::Texture& tile_atlas::get_atlas()
{
    return atlas_texture;
}
```

I am trying to fix this code to remove vertical artifacts so the above image will always look like this no matter if moving the view or zooming in/out.

[image: tilemap as expected]

## [code for answer]

**Using @Mario's answer this is the code I wrote (at the bottom of main.cpp) that completely fixed the artifacts.
here is a great link showing an example.**
https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-draw.php#off-screen-drawing

```
    #ifdef _DEBUG
        app.clear();
    #endif // DEBUG
        //map.draw(app, dt);


        /*-----------------------------------------------------------*/
        // Draw the texture
        //rt.clear();

        rt.draw(map.at(0));
        rt.display();
        if (cam.getSize().x < 500)
        {
            rt.setSmooth(false);
        }
        else
        {
            rt.setSmooth(true);
        }
        //// get the target texture (where the stuff has been drawn)
        const sf::Texture& texture = rt.getTexture();

        sf::Sprite sprite(texture);

        app.draw(sprite);

        //app.draw(map.at(0));

        /*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

        app.display();
```

Comment: You can try changing `gx * tile_size_float + tile_size_float` to `(gx + 1) * tile_size_float`, so that the vertex coords are calculated the same way.  Due to precision of a `float`, you can get slightly different results for "N*x+x" vs "(N+1)*X".

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thank you for the reply, I just changed that in the code, and still get the artifacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, yet effective:

Render your pixels 1:1 without scaling to a render texture and then upscale that instead.

Might be a bit tricky to  determine the correct position, zoom, etc. but it can be done.

Comment: This is an idea, but that is a lot of extra work, memory, time making textures and all visual objects multiple of zoom levels like 32x32, 28x28, 24x24... I know that some other scale zooms work then 1:1 since I have manually found a couple levels that work perfectly.. but there is little rhyme and reason to some of them. I feel like this is the nuclear option. I would like to hope there is a better way to scale textures in SFML, that wont force me to make 6x the number of textures. or a way to programmatically scale the texture files so I don't have to spend 6x the time creating textures.

Comment: I might misunderstand your Answer, can you give an example of "Render your pixels 1:1 without scaling to a render texture and then upscale that instead"

Comment: @Theisen Based on your zoom level you should only have a very limited area on screen, like 80x60 pixels rather than the 800x600 pixels of your window. So you use an 800x600 image and the the visible area on it but without zoom, then use a `sf::Sprite` to draw just those 80x60 pixels.

Comment: Can you give a code example? I'm not sure how to do that once a render texture. Are you talking about taking a 80x60 pixel to stop off screen drawing? (I believe that rendertexture does this on its own.) That would be hard due to the fact I am using vertex arrays, and if I draw 1 pixel of a 20x20 tile vertex array I have to draw the whole array (much better performance than not using vertex array). I do plan to programmatically check if the chunk is in view to draw or skip. So I don't draw to render texture chunks that are never going to be displayed.

Comment: @Theisen Create a render texture as big as your window, draw everything to your render texture (no zoom or rotation). Use a sprite to draw the texture on screen, applying rotation, zoom, etc. It's that hint enough?